# Payment method that can only be selected in admin UI

Tags: commerce

How can I make a payment method only available to select when an admin is manually entering an order in the admin UI, and not visible to customers when checking out normally?

Restricting the payment method to the customer role of admin does not work, presumably because the logged in admin is not seen as the actual customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a custom condition plugin, as described here: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/core/conditions